# DevTools failed to load SourceMap in noty.js.map

Tags: javascript, noty

I'm trying to get a notification on addition of a product in cart but getting this warning, don't know what is causing it.

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/js/noty.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

```
I have installed 'noty' using yarn

import axios from 'axios'
import Noty from 'noty'

function updateCart(pizza) {
    axios.post('/update-cart', pizza).then(res => {
        cartCounter.innerText = res.data.totalQty
        new Noty({
            type: 'success',
            timeout: 1000,
            text: 'Item added to cart',
            progressBar: false,
        }).show();
    }).catch(err => {
        new Noty({
            type: 'error',
            timeout: 1000,
            text: 'Something went wrong',
            progressBar: false,
        }).show();
    })
}

addToCart.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let pizza = JSON.parse(btn.dataset.pizza)
        updateCart(pizza)
    })
})
```

scss

```
@import '~noty/src/noty.scss';
@import '~noty/src/themes/mint.scss';

.noty_theme_mint {
    border-radius: 50px!important;
    padding-left: 8px!important;
}
```